# Cannot Exclude Swap Directory from Spotlight: The item couldn't be added or removed because of an unknown error

Tags: spotlight, power, cpu, indexing, mds

Since my Macbook Pro (Big Sur 11.6) is burning through its battery power really quickly with `mds_store` clocking the most CPU usage, running the following command

```
sudo fs_usage -w -f filesys mds_stores
```

shows that `/System/Volumes/VM/swapfile10` is commonly being used by `mds_store`. Running `sudo fs_usage | grep /System/Volumes/VM/swapfile10` shows that this file is constantly being used by Brave Browser.

However, when I tried to exclude `/System/Volumes/VM/` from being indexed by Spotlight by going to `System Preference > Spotlight > Privacy`, I get a `Privacy List Error`, stating that

> The item couldn't be added or removed because of an unknown error.

[image]

How can we fix this and exclude the directory from Spotlight indexing?